# pyodbc AccessDB TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')

Tags: ms-access, pyodbc

Running Python 3.7.2  32 bit on Windows 7 and using pyodbc package 4.0.25-cp27 32bit

I have tried multiple ways of passing through the params and keep getting the above error:

> TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')

my inputfile is a txt file containing this:

```
TEST ,EU ,Totals , 30, 0.61, 0.00000000,GOLD ,01/03/2019,   
TEST ,EU ,SubTotals , 40, 0.63, 0.00000000,GOLD ,01/03/2019,
```

A few versions:

```
qry = """INSERT INTO newtable ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5], [Col6], [Col7], [Col8]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"""  

with open (inputfile, "r") as afile:  
    for line in afile:  
        params = tuple(line.split(','))  
        cursor.executemany(qry, params)  
conn.commit()
```

for the params value also tried:

```
params = list(line.split(','))
```

Also tried inserting all values into the list one by one:

```
params = list(line.split(","))  
a = params[0]  
b = params[1]  
c = params[2]  
d = params[3]   
e = params[4]  
f = params[5]  
g = params[6]  
h = params[7]  
dbparams = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]   
cursor.executemany(qry,dbparams)
```

Comment: What's inside ``inputfile``?

Comment: If, as you loop through the lines in the file, you are only adding one row per iteration then try `.execute` instead of `.executemany`

Comment: I have updated the post above as cant seem to add it in here without 2 lines becoming 1

Comment: I have added in def insert_data() with the first example and I now get a different error - the SQL contains 8 parameter markers, but 9 parameters were supplied. when I print (qry,params) it does have an extra parameter of ''\n' which I guess is causing this. So trying the 3rd exampe above again with the insert_data() function to specify just the 8 params and I just get the first error again that is in the subject title. So I need to somehow ignore that \n

Comment: got it!!! actually answered it myself when i typed my last comment. so after adding the insert_data() function I just did this to insert the first 8 parameters: cursor.execute(qry, params[0:8])

Comment: and just to add using the second example of params = line.split(',') worked just as well, I did not need to convert to tuple class.

Comment: latest update, I didnt need the insert_data() function either. i just removed. So I realised i did change from executemany to execute also,as @gordthompson suggested. Moral of the story, winning result is simply a combination of using execute and only using first 8 results of the list: cursor.execute(qry, params[0:8]). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

cursor.execute(qry, params[0:8]) worked

The executemany was causing the error - params must be in list, tuple or row

and without the [0:8] the list was passing through a '\n' at the end of the list causing the error - the SQL contains 8 parameter markers, but 9 parameters were supplied

Winning answer was:

cursor.execute(qry, params[0:8]) worked

thanks to @gordthompson for his prompt