# loading floats into SQL server using executemany in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, pyodbc

I am reading in some sensor data from a source that gives me a list of floats. example:

sensor_data = [1.1, 2.2, 1.3, 2.5]

I want to load these values using pyodbc's "execute_many" function; however from testing, I have verified that the data needs to be in this format in order to be loaded:

formattedArray = [[(1.1)], [(2.2)], [(1.3)], [(2.5)]]

What is the simplest way to do this conversion? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

I realize that this problem is related to:

[pyodbc AccessDB TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024559/pyodbc-accessdb-typeerror-params-must-be-in-a-list-tuple-or-row-hy000)

However I have tried doing that in my executemany method as well.

```
data = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
conn = pyodbc.connect(myString) 
cur = conn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany('insert into testTable (col) values(?);'(data[0:3]))
conn.commit()
```

I get this output:

TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
data_new = [(elem,) for elem in data]
```

will return:

```
[(1.1,), (2.2,), (3.3,), (4.4,)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I need the result to not have the comma inside the tuple though.  I think this may get me on the right track though

Comment: This commas are really shows that the element is a tuple, not an expression in parenthesis. It is actually a 1-element tuple, what you see is what Python prints to console to show that they are tuples.

Comment: I tried it in my script and I am still getting: TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')

Comment: Oops, you show a list of list of tuples. IMHO you went one step too far: `execute_many` expects a sequence of tuples, lists or Rows. So this should be enough: `data_new = [(elem,) for elem in data]`

Comment: wow I made stupid typo, yes it does work, thank you both! Marked solved.